# Appending a string with unknown charcters to another string not working

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I need to send a file as POST request, so i converted the file to bytes then to string by the following:

```
 string file = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(param.ToString()))
```

which resulted in the following string, the string is longer than this put i trim it:

```
lengthi131072e6:pieces6620:��9���[�F�j�xs~ =�Z��L��Г��>�d������{���&ut�%t�Sƍ�:[�*�I* ŀ�|<4S�1Ĉt�p�Jߊg$K�"
```

When i try to append any string to this string like this:

```
file = file + "AnyText";
```

The "AnyText" is ignored completely and "file" value remains the same.

Note that i need to convert the file to string and append some other parameters to it as this is a requirement in order for the request to work.

Edit:

I use fiddler2, and when i POST'ed the same file, the string i got is the same string as the one i posted above. Here is the POST in fiddler2:

```
  ------WebKitFormBoundaryAiZYKGjC4Yd8E9z4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent

 lengthi131072e6:pieces6620:��9���[�F�j�xs~ =�Z��L��Г��>�d������{���&ut�%t�Sƍ�:[�*�I* ŀ�|<4S�1Ĉt�p�Jߊg$K���6\c�x;���,��ȡ
```

if there is anyway to produce the same result i am all ears.

Comment: Arbitrary byte arrays can not be converted to string. But you may want to use Base64 encoding...

Comment: "The "AnyText" is ignored completely and "file" value remains the same." I *very* much doubt this. Try printing `file.Length` before and after, for example. What is the content of your file? I suspect it's not text, so you shouldn't be using a string.

Comment: It isn't ignored, you just can't see it in the debugger.  The bytes you converted are junk and include a binary zero.  Which acts as a string terminator in many cases, including the debugger output.  You need to stop converting junk, it isn't utf-8 encoded text.

Comment: I used fiddler2 to see what is the data POST'ed, and the string i have is the same one i got in fiddler2 so it's not junk. I tried using Base64 string but didn't work for me.

Comment: It's not UTF8 so `Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString` is not going to work. How did you “tried using Base64” and what does “didn't work ” mean?

Comment: I converted the file to Base64 string and then added the other parameters and send the request, but i got a wrong response.

Comment: oh.. downvoters, do you think that if i knew the answer i would bother asking. It seems that anybody that doesn't like the question simply downvote it which is ..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did make a mistake in converting the file to UTF8 because it's meaningless. What solved my problem was converting the file to byte[] and all the other string parameters too. I joined them all together and send them in a POST and it worked.